# Conda displaying (base) multiple times

Tags: bash, macos, anaconda, conda

Something odd is happening when I type source ~/.bash_profile into my terminal.

```
jakem:~ jake$ conda activate base
```

```
(base) jakem:~ jake$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

```
(base) (base) jakem:~ jake$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

```
(base) (base) (base) jakem:~ jake$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

```
(base) (base) (base) (base) jakem:~ jake$
```

each time that I source ~/.bash_profile, another (base) is added indicating which conda environment I am using. Why is this? Is there something wrong with my conda install, or is this normal/ okay? I would appreciate any help. I am using bash on an m1 mac for context.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I had a line in my ~/.bash_profile that basically activated base again. This was left over from an old conda installation. I had commented out all of the lines except for this one apparently.

```
CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
```

commenting out this line solved the issue